# Convert int to time Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter, I want to know that is there a way to convert integer to time before inserting into a table in codeigniter? because i have this kind of error. Error Number: 22018

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with time

INSERT INTO ScheduleDummy (Sched_Day, Sched_StartTime, Sched_EndTime) VALUES (0, 0, 0)

Filename: E:\Xampp\htdocs\Student\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331
```

Comment: php's [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is your friend.

Comment: add your insert function as well

Answer (score 0):

Try the strtotime php function. It would be helpful